# what is a good approach to set global variables in a node module?

Tags: node.js

I have a module test1.js, I can require it from test2.js, now I'd like to set up some global variable info that test1.js can use, what is a good approach? Thanks,

```
// test1.js
exports.foo = function (jcontent, cb) {
console.log('foo', this.info)
}
```

here is the test2.js

```
// test2.js
var test1 = require('./test2.js')

// set up a value in info inside test1? how?

test1.foo()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447771/node-js-global-variables)

Comment: `var test1 = require('./test1.js')` would make more sense.

Comment: correct, it should have been test1 = require('./test1.js')

Comment: Reffer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45911838/7635845 you will get an idea